# Saving, Switching between window arrangements?

Tags: macos, productivity, spaces

**Repeating series of actions := productivity lost.**

Is there a way I can arrange, and save for later loading, an arbitrary arrangement of open programs, closed programs, and arrangement of windows?

*The "reopen windows after restart" checkbox comes to mind...*

---

Dramatization follows:

Task A: terminal, browser, another browser different session, IDE files, notes, finder.
Task B: two terminals, same browsers different tabs, same IDE different files, new note.

On break... Wikipedia and Wolfram Alpha everywhere. Inspiration strikes! aaannnndddd.... four minutes setting up a workspace. Why.

Configuring workspaces per task is:

- most frequent and least productive task of any type,
- most time consuming, esp. when comparing all set-up time to any one task's time,
- repeated verbatim ideally, predictably otherwise.

---

*In the absence of a unified solution, please provide any meaningful information, eg. where is the arrangement stored for the "reopen windows after restart" feature, and where does OS X keep track of open window positions?*